# Apt-get upgrade issues

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt

I'm having an issue upgrading

Here are some of reports

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae_3.2.0-44.69_i386.deb


server@philo:/$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

So I tried this...

```
server@philo:/mnt/halftb/media/Videos$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-pae
```

Heres a ton of output...

```
(Reading database ... 80098 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae_3.2.0-44.69_i386.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae_3.2.0-44.69_i386.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic-pae': No space left on device
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-44-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-44-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
Preparing to replace libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.8 (using .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.9_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libssl1.0.0 ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae_3.2.0-44.69_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
server@philo:/mnt/halftb/media/Videos$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptitude bash-completion cifs-utils cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-ppdc libasound2 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libgnutls26 libtiff4 linux-image-generic-pae linux-libc-dev openssl python-apt python-apt-common rsyslog smbfs
28 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/46.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 113 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
server@philo:/mnt/halftb/media/Videos$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libssl1.0.0 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-libc-dev (3.2.0-43.68) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic-pae
server@philo:/mnt/halftb/media/Videos$
```

edits-
additional:

```
server@philo:~$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
[sudo] password for server:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic-pae but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Why dont you try this first `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0`?

Comment: I tried a few variants of that, endless loop. I updated the post to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be a lack of space on /boot:

So, I went to /boot and found a ton of old kernels:

I deleted all except the last three (just to have some fallback :) and ran the apt-get install command again.  Worked this time.

Hope this helps,
PS

*edit* - I pasted some output but it didn't format correctly so I removed it.

Comment: How do you know which is a new vs old kernel ? My boot is way close to being full but I'm not sure how to remove the old kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I ran these except not "dist". I don't want to upgrade the distribution. No change.

Comment: dist-upgrade is not necessarily to upgrade the distribution, though. (It is used when `apt-get` must remove packages or install new ones in order to update completely.)